Issue with 1 Port of 4port Reaktek 8125 NIC not recognized
I had a dual port Realtek 8125 NIC and it worked great for a week until one day one of the ports just disappeared. Thinking that it was just a bad port I replaced it and this time with a 4 port 8125. The NIC was recognized and when I configured it I noticed that Ubuntu only recognized 3 of the 4 ports. Thinking it was the driver I updated it to the Realtek ones on their website. Rebooted and still only 3 ports recognized.  There is an integrated 4port NIC on the motherboard but I have the ports disabled (all 4 of those were recognized).  Does anyone have any ideas?
seth@docker:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-119-generic

seth@docker:~$ sudo dmesg |grep r8125
[    2.077623] r8125: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.079494] r8125: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.080367] r8125: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.080455] r8125: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.115179] r8125 Ethernet controller driver 9.013.02-NAPI loaded
[    2.133155] r8125 0000:0a:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0143)
[    2.271197] r8125: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[    2.334741] r8125  Copyright (C) 2024 Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
[    2.452785] r8125 Ethernet controller driver 9.013.02-NAPI loaded
[    2.465653] r8125 0000:0b:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0143)
[    2.550927] r8125: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[    2.553896] r8125  Copyright (C) 2024 Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
[    2.554637] r8125 Ethernet controller driver 9.013.02-NAPI loaded
[    2.554662] r8125 0000:0c:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0143)
[    2.568244] r8125: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[    2.602266] r8125  Copyright (C) 2024 Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
[    2.932716] r8125 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0: renamed from eth0
[    3.100734] r8125 0000:0b:00.0 enp11s0: renamed from eth1
[    3.136919] r8125 0000:0c:00.0 enp12s0: renamed from eth3
[    9.975508] r8125: enp12s0: link up
[   10.023580] r8125: enp11s0: link up
[   10.223683] r8125: enp10s0: link up

seth@docker:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: enp10s0
       version: 05
       serial: 98:b7:85:xx:xx:xx
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8125 driverversion=9.013.02-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.12.41 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:80700000-8070ffff memory:80710000-80713fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: enp11s0
       version: 05
       serial: 98:b7:85:xx:xx:xx
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8125 driverversion=9.013.02-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.13.5.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:80600000-8060ffff memory:80610000-80613fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: enp12s0
       version: 05
       serial: 98:b7:85:xx:xx:xx
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8125 driverversion=9.013.02-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.100.12.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:80500000-8050ffff memory:80510000-80513fff

--
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8125
    Kernel modules: r8125
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8125
    Kernel modules: r8125
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8125
    Kernel modules: r8125


Sorry it is Ubuntu Server 22.04
